# Windows installed Windows Boot Manager on Linux SSD. Linux doesn't boot blue Windows screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, bootloader

I have 2 SSD: one had Kubuntu installed and the second one I tried to install Windows on. I didn't disconnect the Linux SSD before doing that and Windows installed its Boot Manager on the Linux SSD. Now Linux doesn't boot.

Now I have this (when using live USB with Kubuntu):

[image]

What should I do to fix it?

**I tried changing boot order, but it doesn't work - after reboot, I still get the blue screen.** And Windows boot comes before the Linux once again.

Should I try removing the Windows Boot Manager partition?

Comment: Is this an HP? They typically need UEFI update & then you only can change boot order in UEFI settings tab (not boot manager/menu). Is blue screen from Windows? post this `sudo efibootmgr -v`, not screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the windows drive and use the procedure here.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

If the windows needs repair to boot, disconnect the linux drive and here.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of EasyUEFI in Windows and EasyBCD (also in Windows) then, if needed, follow the answer submitted by HappyTux.

Answer (score 0):

Had to reinstall Linux. I hope one day someone would sue Windows over it. I asked it to install itself on a specific drive, while it deemed fit to corrupt my other drives. Quite worthy a lawsuit, if you ask me.